# Hot Chocolate can't set default value for field of input type

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I have a class with an enum field declared like this:

```
public class PostPhotoInput
{

    [DefaultValue(PhotoCategory.Portrait)]
    public PhotoCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

I expect it to produce SDL that looks like this:

```
input PostPhotoInput {
    category: PhotoCategory = PORTRAIT
}
```

Instead, when I reload the docs in Altair, I get the error:
**Could not parse the native value of input field 'PostPhotoInput.category'.**

How do I get the desired SDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that will be fixed with this PR:
https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/pull/4129